# Get nth read from mth chromosome in a van file

Tags: c++, bioinformatics

I'm currently using htslib (though I could use bamtools as well) and am able to get consecutive reads via something like [this](https://gist.github.com/PoisonAlien/350677acc03b2fbf98aa) but I'm curious how I might edit this code to get the nth read from the mth chromosome rather than reading through it consecutively. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can jump straight to the `m`th chromosome, but you'll then need to linearly search for the `n`th read.

Instead of `sam_read1()` and given an `htsFile *` (`bamFile`) corresponding to a file named `bamFileName`, one would:

```
hts_idx_t *idx = sam_index_load(bamFile, bamFileName);
hts_itr_t *itr = sam_itr_queryi(idx, m, 0, hdr->targetLen[m]);
```

Then use `sam_itr_next(bamFile, itr, b)` to get successive alignments in `b`, which is a `bam1_t*`.